Why does GCC generate different types for the same lambda in a template context?
I've been playing around with stateful metaprogramming for a while.
I have discovered a weird behaviour in GCC
#include <type_traits>

//removing template will make it compile
template <typename = void>
void test() {
    // Replacing lambda with any other type will make it compile as well
    using NonDependentStaticType = decltype([](){});
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<NonDependentStaticType, NonDependentStaticType>);
}

int main() {
    test();
}

This code compiles for both latest clang and MSVC, but fails for GCC.
Am I correct that regardless of how compilers handle a default lambda template parameters the static_assert must not fail?
live example
UPDATE: Thanks to @Jarod42 for simplified code example

Is it mandatory to infer the type of the default template argument on each instantiation? and If a lambda is declared inside a default argument, is it different for each call site?

@user12002570 it's not the same question of course. This one has nothing to do with multiple instantiations, because there is only one.

It's just another variation of the original dupe where cwg2300 is mentioned.

@user12002570 I don't see that as the same thing. gcc does the same thing as the others in that case which can be noticed by instantiating the type (example). The static_assert failure that you get if uncommenting that line is a bit surprising since it has clearly instantiated the same type.

I added bug 116714


Am I correct that regardless of how compilers handle a default lambda template parameters the static_assert must not fail?

Yes. It was a bug in gcc (for which I wrote 116714) and it has now been fixed for gcc 15 as you can verify yourself by rerunning your live example which uses gcc trunk.
